# Marketo Munchkin js error

Tags: javascript, marketo

I use Muchkin.js enabled in Marketo on my website and somehow getting this error in console - GET https://%20596-oey-331%20.mktoresp.com/webevents/visitWebPage?_mchNc=148758…ard%2F&_mchPc=https%3A&_mchVr=151&_mchHa=&_mchRe=&_mchQp=profile%3Dcreated net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Any idea what this means and how to fix it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like some spaces have crept in to your url in your munchkin code... If you look at the script snippet you pasted in to your template, check if there are any spaces around your instance ID (which would be `596-OEY-331`). There shouldn't be any spaces - it should be like `Munchkin.init('596-OEY-331')` - see if that works!

Comment: excatly! spaces were a problem. Thanks a lot!